# Custom search engine

Tags: search

I have made a web application and now I would like to add a search option to it.
Since it is a learning project, I can't afford to buy some Google license. That is why I consider creating my own search engine.

From what I have read, there are two major ways to do it: using `Apache Lucene` or using `Apache Solr`. I have read a bit about both, but I really don't understand what is the difference between them. Which one should I choose?

I am looking for something free which is easy to learn and use, so you have other suggestions please let me know.

Comment: This question is likely to solicit debate, which makes it off topic for this web site. You may want to try Apache mailing lists or forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucene is a search engine and Solr is a search application.
With search engine you have to create everything from scratch, with search application you have everything out of the box.

Lucene is more shared-hosting friendly.
You can create a basic search engine (without scoring, faceted search, etc) in an hour or two.

If your hosting provider allows you to install Solr, go for it.
Otherwise Lucene should be just fine.

Solr is built on top of Lucene so everything you can do with Solr can be done with Lucene and few extra lines of code.

Comment: Thank you. I have no idea about how should I build that application. How long should it take until I will be able to search myapplication(where the results are links, like in every other search engine)? (I know that I a pushing it too far, but I really need an estimation in order to make a decision.)

Comment: I would recommend looking at Elastic Search, it's a decent replacement for Sorl.

Answer (score 1):

[Solr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solr) is the search platform which internally uses [lucene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucene) API.

according to your requirement ,you may go for [Solr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solr)

in 2010 both are merged.